# Scala UDF: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I am trying to use Scala for UDFs, but the Pig job is failing with the 
error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject". What am I doing wrong?

$ cat NonEmpty.scala

```
package nonempty

import org.apache.pig.FilterFunc
import org.apache.pig.data._

class NonEmpty extends FilterFunc {
  def exec(input: Tuple) = {
    val s = input.get(0)
    s match {
    case a: String => !a.isEmpty 
    case _ => false
   }
  }
}
```

$ cat ex3.pig

```
register ./nonempty.jar 
register ./scala-library.jar;

define NonEmpty nonempty.NonEmpty();

raw = load 'excite-small.log' using PigStorage('\t') as (user: chararray, time:chararray, query: chararray);

locations = filter raw by NonEmpty(query);
```

Build:

```
scalac -cp ~/pig-0.9.2/pig-0.9.2.jar NonEmpty.scala
jar -cf nonempty.jar nonempty
```

Pig Stack Trace:

```
2 ---------------
3 ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. scala/ScalaObject
4 
5 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject
(...)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ScalaObject` is located in the `scala-library.jar` which needs to be included on the runtime classpath. So add `scala-library.jar` to the runtime classpath of your command that is running the program.